# Problem on solving Partial Differential Equations with Gekko Python

Tags: python, ode, gekko, pde

I get a converging solution while trying to solve a Partial Differential Equation attached below.

In my code, I want to calculate a volume flow rate over time by integrating 2*pi*r*v(r)*dr . I have used scipy.integrate.trapz to solve this inside the code m.GEKKO().

I want to have a graph of Qgap vs time. When I execute the code, I get a single Qgap value in the solution.

Please help me.

All the details can be easily found through this article <<**Modeling of a hydraulic damper with shear thinning fluid for damping mechanism analysis**>> by Sujuan Jiao et al.

The velocity profile is discretised by 100 points in space between r1 and r1+delta with BC at r1=u (piston velocity) and 0 at the wall.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate

amp=10e-2
freq=10
tf = 2/freq
omega=2*np.pi*freq
npt = 101
time = np.linspace(0,tf,npt)

xglob=amp*np.sin(omega*time)
uglob=amp*omega*np.cos(omega*time)

delta=0.007
npx=100
dx=np.float32(delta/npx)

r1=0.01
r2=0.004
xpos = np.linspace(r1,r1+delta,npx)
Ap=np.pi*(r1**2-r2**2)

rho=850
beta=5e8
L=0.06
l=0.01

pressf=12*amp*0.707*uglob\
        *np.cos(2*np.pi*freq*time)/(delta**2)\
        *630*(1+(0.05*(0.707*uglob/delta)**2))**(-0.23)

m = GEKKO()

def Q(r,v):
    Q=(2*np.pi*r*np.transpose(np.array(v)))
    return scipy.integrate.trapz(Q,r) 

m.time = time
t=m.Param(m.time)

x=m.MV(ub=amp+1)
x.value=np.ones(npt)*xglob
u=m.MV(ub=10)
u.value=np.ones(npt)*uglob

pf=m.MV(lb=20)
pf.value=np.ones(npt)*pressf

u1=[m.Var(1) for i in range(npx)]
p1=m.Var(800000)
p2=m.Var(800000)
Qgap=Q(xpos,u1)

m.Equation(u1[0].dt()==-1*(p1-p2+pf)/l  \
           + ((630 * (1+(0.05*((u-u1[0])/dx))**2)**(-0.23))/rho)\
           *((u-2*u1[0]+u1[1])/(dx*dx)))
m.Equations([(u1[i].dt()==-1*(p1-p2+pf)/l  \
           + ((630 * (1+(0.05*((u1[i+1]-u1[i-1])/(2*dx)))**2)**(-0.23))/rho)\
              *((u1[i+1]-2*u1[i]+u1[i-1])/(dx*dx))) for i in range(1,npx-1)])
m.Equation(u1[-1].dt()==-1*(p1-p2+pf)/l  \
           + (((630 * (1+(0.05*((u1[-1]-0)/dx))**2)**(-0.23)))/rho)\
           *((u1[-2]-2*u1[-1]+0)/(dx*dx)))
m.Equation(p1.dt()==(beta/(Ap*(L-x)))*(-Qgap+Ap*u))
m.Equation(p2.dt()==(beta/(Ap*(L+x)))*(Qgap-Ap*u))

# simulation
m.options.IMODE = 4
m.options.solver=1
m.options.nodes=3

m.solve(disp=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the problem solves successfully:

```
 Iter    Objective  Convergence
   50  6.52927E-21  1.43369E-03
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :    36.8693000000021      sec
 Objective      :   0.000000000000000E+000
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

It is not using the `scipy.integrate.trapz()` function inside the Gekko model. Gekko builds a symbolic model. See `gk0_model.apm` in `m.path` or use `m.open_folder()` to open the run folder.

There is an `m.integral()` function in gekko, but this integrates with respect to time. You likely need to write out the [collocation equations](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/OrthogonalCollocation) or the integral in Gekko equation form.

Comment: Hello Sir. I have tried to understand the collocation equations but with no chance of doing it.
I have come to another solution which converges a bit earlier setting Qgap as a m.Equation.